# Spark Checkpoint partition can not be casted to CoGroup Partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a Spark Streaming application. At the very end I send data back to driver and send data to S3 and Kinesis using `foreachRDD`. The program can run for a while, usually hours, then encounter this error which crashes the job. The error message says:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.CheckpointRDDPartition cannot be cast to 
org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupPartition
```

I am using `Spark 2.4.0` on `Amazon EMR 5.23.0`. I have no idea why this is happening. I am guessing when some error happen (maybe the data to be written or to be sent to driver is too large? again I am not sure since I do not see memory error message) the checkpointed data just can not be reloaded back when spark tried to revive from the situation due to this strange error `CheckpointRDDPartition can not be cast to CoGroupPartition`

I have done some research in Google but there is nothing related I could find. So I am looking for help from Spark gurus here.

Here are what's happening at end of my streaming app where I send data to various targets, which seems to all cause the error sometimes:

1: send data to akka actor:

```
mydstream.foreachRDD( rdd => {
        for (item <- rdd.collect().toArray) {
          reporter ! item
        }
      })
```

2: send data to ElasticSearch:

```
mydstream.foreachRDD(rdd=> {
            rdd.saveToEs("index1", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))
          })
```

3: send data to S3:

```
mydstream.repartition(1)
          .foreachRDD(rdd => {
              rdd.toDF.write
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("quote", null) 
                .option("accessKey", aws_access_key_id)
                .option("secretKey", aws_secret_access_key)
                .option("bucket", bucketName)
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)              
                .save(s"s3a://mybucketName/mydata.csv")
            })
```

4: send data to kinesis:

```
mydstream.foreachRDD(rdd => 
            rdd.saveToKinesis(
              streamName = kinesis_stream,
              region = Regions.fromName(kinesis_region),
              chunk = 1
            )
          )
```

Here are the error messages:

```
2019-08-26 09:26:54,394 ERROR [JobScheduler] org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler:Error running job streaming job 1566811320000 ms.7
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 149 in stage 1132.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 149.3 in stage 1132.0 (TID 125739, ip-172-17-32-5.ec2.internal, executor 4): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.CheckpointRDDPartition cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupPartition
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionwiseSampledRDD.compute(PartitionwiseSampledRDD.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2039)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2026)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2026)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2260)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2209)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2198)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at iCatchU$$anonfun$main$7.apply(iCatchU.scala:649)
    at iCatchU$$anonfun$main$7.apply(iCatchU.scala:643)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.CheckpointRDDPartition cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupPartition
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$compute$2.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.compute(CoGroupedRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionwiseSampledRDD.compute(PartitionwiseSampledRDD.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    ... 3 more
```